# Is there a way to use JOIN function on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Number_of_Trips TIMEPART    member_casual
46477             00               casual
30162             00               casual
18686             01               member
11112             01               casual
7619              05               member
12436             05               member
```

I have a table where TIMEPART is same for both member_casual, however whenever I am trying to write a query to get a result where the member and casual number of trips can come on separate column correponding to their TIME PART.

I am trying to get a result like this

```
TIMEPART  members   Casuals
00         46477     30162                      
01         18686     11112                      
05         7619      12436
```

Comment: In TSQL language no join function

Comment: Instead , it is an operator. Simply join fields how is needed.

Comment: In this case there are no restrictions.

Comment: Why do you expect 12436 in the last row & column? The input data does not have anything for that combination... Seems you have not given us the good input data and have mixed up the values in the last column.

Comment: I don't get your expected output. Your input has only `casual` for timepart `00`, yet, your output as `casuals` and `members`? How do you determine which number goes where ...? Same for timepart `05`, you only have `member` but the result has both?

Comment: The last 05 was assigned to casuals, mistakenly I mentioned both as members

Comment: SELECT TIMEPART    , SUM(CASE member_casual = 'member' THEN Number END) ETCC ) FROM Some GROUP BY TIMEPART

Comment: Using two SUM CASEs will response your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you may get this result if you use PIVOT

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    your_table PIVOT( 
        MAX(number_of_trips) FOR member_casual IN (
            'casual' AS Casuals
            , 'member' AS Members
        )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `timepart` and use  `sum` with a `case when` filter for the two categories:

```
select   timepart, 
         sum(CASE member_casual WHEN 'casual' THEN number_of_trips END) as casuals, 
         sum(CASE member_casual WHEN 'member' THEN number_of_trips END) as members 
from     trips
group by timepart;
```

Note that your input example and desired output do not match -- probably because of some typos.